# Как удалить записи SQL запросом с подзапросом?

Tags: mysql, sql

Использую такой запрос

```
DELETE FROM user_todo_send WHERE id_user IN (SELECT uts.id_user FROM user_todo_send uts INNER JOIN todo ON todo.id = uts.id_todo WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, NOW(),  todo.time_created) > uts.time )
```

Получаю ошибку в ответ - 
You can't specify target table 'user_todo_send' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение - обернуть упоминание таблицы в подзапрос:

```
DELETE FROM user_todo_send WHERE id_user IN
(   
    SELECT tempT.id_user FROM 
    (
        SELECT uts.id_user AS id_user FROM user_todo_send uts 
        INNER JOIN todo ON todo.id = uts.id_todo 
        WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, NOW(),  todo.time_created) > uts.time
    ) AS tempT
)
```

это приведет к неявному копированию данных во временную таблицу и позволит обойти ограничение на упоминание обновляемой таблицы.

<sub>[взято из ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302701/1988244)</sub>

Comment: Спасибо! работает!  я так понял мы здесь создаем временную переменную в которой сохраняем результат? а потом производим операцию удаления

Comment: @modelfak не настолько знаю mysql, но насколько я понял - mysql просто явно копирует данные во временную таблицу. это просто ограничение движка - в mssql, например, механизм выполнения запросов вполне такое позволяет.

Comment: А возможно ли сделать еще и UPDATE одновременно в таблице todo?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению не знаю про MySQL, но в MS SQL можно использовать такую форму запроса:

```
delete uts
from user_todo_send uts inner join todo t on todo.id = uts.id_todo
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, NOW(), t.time_created) > uts.time;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но еще нужно как-то UPDATE cделать в таблице todo после выборки но до удаления записей