# Mysql удаление копий

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. 
Не силён в sql, но есть необходимость удалить все копии записей, кроме первой, где Name одинаковый.

Пробую сделать через:

```
DELETE FROM Login
WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT max(Name) FROM Login GROUP BY Name HAVING 
count(Name)>1)
```

Но получаю ошибку
`You can't specify target table 'Login' for update in FROM clause`

Пробовал сделать по аналогии с [Как удалить записи SQL запросом с подзапросом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428314/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc)

Но ничего не вышло.

Приблизительно так:

```
DELETE FROM Login
WHERE Name NOT IN (
  (SELECT tempT.Login
   FROM (SELECT Name WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT max(Name) FROM Login GROUP BY Name HAVING count(Name) > 1))
          AS tempT)
)
```

Тут много вариантов перепробовал. 
Прошу помощи.

Comment: *удалить все копии записей, кроме первой* Чем определяется "первость"? Ответ "выше при выводе таблицы" - не принимается.

Comment: Определяется по id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для записей с одинаковым `Name` оставляем только запись с максимальным `id`:

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM Login t1
JOIN Login t2 USING (Name)
WHERE t1.id < t2.id
```

Нужен минимальный - поменять знак сравнения.